# Error (WinError 123 ) when using os.rename() to rename Naruto video files

Tags: python, project, file-rename

I was writing a python script to rename Naruto videos with messy titles. Here's the code:

```
import os
import re


def rename_files():
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Caleb\Videos\Anime\Naruto Shippuden")
    files = os.listdir('.')
    for file in files:
        nameRegex = re.compile(r'.?(Naruto(-?)).'
                               r'(Shi(p)+(u)+den)'
                               r'(_-_|\s-\s|\sEpisode\s|-_Season_17_Episode_| Episode |_)'
                               r'((\d\d\d)(-\d\d\d)?)', re.I)

        mo = nameRegex.search(file)
        if mo is None:
            print(f'({file} Not found)')
            continue
        ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        old_name = ext[0] + ext[1]
        new_name = f"{mo.group(1).title()} {mo.group(3).title()}, Episode: {mo.group(7)}{ext[1]}"
        os.rename(old_name, new_name)


rename_files()
```

I used os.rename() but it kept throwing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\Desktop\Python\rename_files.py", line 28, in <module>
    rename_files()
  File "C:\Users\Caleb\Desktop\Python\rename_files.py", line 25, in rename_files
    os.rename(old_name, new_name)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '(Hi10)_Naruto_Shippuuden_-_003_(480p)_(SD).mkv' -> 'Naruto Shippuuden, Episode: 003.mkv'
```

What can i do to solve this error? I've been stuck for days

Comment: Colon isn't allowed in a file name (at least on Windows).

Comment: What part of the code, can you specify please

Comment: The part where you create a new file name. A colon (`:`) is not allowed as part of a file name.

Comment: Ohhh you mean the "C:\" ?

Comment: No, you create a new file name to rename the file to. This new name contains a colon as the error message clearly shows.

Comment: Ohh  thanks alot, didn't know collons weren't allowed